# Two top blobs in train.prototxt when using caffe.NetSpec() in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using *caffe.NetSpec* in `python` to define and export in architecture using the following code :

```
conv1_1 = L.Convolution(data,top='conv1_1',name='conv1_1',
                        convolution_param=
                        {'kernel_size':3,'num_output':64,'pad':1},
                        param=[{'lr_mult':1, 'decay_mult':1},
                               {'lr_mult':2,'decay_mult':0}])
```

But, when generating the `train.protxt`, two Top blobs appears in the  layer as follow :

```
layer {
name: "conv1_1"
type: "Convolution"
bottom: "Data1"
top: "Convolution1"
top: "conv1_1"
param {
  lr_mult: 1
  decay_mult: 1
}
param {
  lr_mult: 2
  decay_mult: 0
}
convolution_param {
  num_output: 64
  pad: 1
  kernel_size: 3
  }
}
```

What's going wrong here? 
Thanks

Comment: @Shai: But I want the name of the top to be 'conv1_1'.

Comment: @Shai: I'm just stacking a bunch of layers and then feed the last layer to the 'to_proto' function. It's a very deep network. You need all the code? Note that the same behavior happens for all layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a `NetSpec()` object?

```
import caffe

ns = caffe.NetSpec() # use this object to store the layers
ns.data, ns.label = L.Data(name='data',  ntop=2, 
                           data_param={'source':'', 'batch_size': 32})
ns.conv1_1 = L.Convolution(ns.data, name='conv1_1',
                    convolution_param=
                    {'kernel_size':3,'num_output':64,'pad':1},
                    param=[{'lr_mult':1, 'decay_mult':1},
                           {'lr_mult':2,'decay_mult':0}])
print str(ns.to_proto()) # print the net stored in ns object
```

Comment: In this way, can we use variables inside the layer 'top's?   For example, `ns.conv1_1`, `ns.conv1_2` etc.  We don't wanna write it so many times, right?